# Dice usuario y clave no valido pero la clave es correcta

Tags: php

estoy haciendo una web que tenga para login usuario y clave. La cosa es que  se conecte a una base de datos y compruebe si el usuario y la clave (ambos columnas de una tabla) coinciden con lo que hay si es asi pues en teoria haria login y me diria bienvenido periquito o el nombre de usuario qeu sea. El problema es que me dice usuario y clave no valida pero es la que hay en la BD.

```
<?php
$pagina = 0;
session_start();
// Comprobamos si ya se ha enviado el formulario
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($usuario) || empty($password))
        $error = "Debes introducir un nombre de usuario y una contraseña";
    else {
        // Comprobamos las credenciales con la base de datos
        // Conectamos a la base de datos
        try {
            $opc = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
            $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userlitdb";
            $dwes = new PDO($dsn, "root", "", $opc);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        // Ejecutamos la consulta para comprobar las credenciales
        $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM users " .
                "WHERE usuario='$usuario' " .
                "AND contrasena='" . md5($password) . "'";

        if ($resultado = $dwes->query($sql)) {
            $fila = $resultado->fetch();
            if ($fila != null) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                header("Location: pagina1.php");
            } else {
                // Si las credenciales no son válidas, se vuelven a pedir
                $error = "Usuario o contraseña no válidos!";
            }
            unset($resultado);
        }
        unset($dwes);
    }
}
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylo.css">


        <title>tarea online hlc 03</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
include'menu.php';
?>

        <div class="principal">
            <div style=" height: 300px; width: 80%; display: block; float: left;">

                <section style=" width: 20%; float: left; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; margin-right: 2px;"><img src="imagenes/logosamsung.png"width="150"></section>

                <section style=" width: 20%; float: left; margin: 2px; padding: 5px;"><img src="imagenes/xiaomi.png" width="150"></section>
                <section style=" width: 20%; float: left; margin: 2px; padding: 5px;">tercera seccion</section>

                <section style=" width: 20%; float: left; margin: 2px; padding: 5px;">cuarta seccion</section>



            </div>
            <div style=" width: 15%; float: left;">
                <aside style=" float: left; margin: 2px; padding: 5px; ">

                    <div id='login'>
                        <form action='index.php' method='post'>
                            <fieldset >
                                <legend>Login</legend>
                                <div><span class='error'><?php echo (isset($error) ? $error : ""); ?></span></div>
                                <div><span class='error'><?php //echo $error;  ?></span></div>
                                <div class='campo'>
                                    <label for='usuario' >Usuario:</label><br/>
                                    <input type='text' name='usuario' id='usuario' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                                </div>
                                <div class='campo'>
                                    <label for='password' >Contraseña:</label><br/>
                                    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                                </div>

                                <div class='campo'>
                                    <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='Enviar' />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div style="width: 100%; float: left;">

        </div>
<?php include'footer.php'; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Os dejo la captura de la BD para que veais que es asi
[image]

Comment: No he trabajo con md5 por temas de seguridad, con temor a equivocarme, en tu base de datos guardaste la contraseña en plano sin encriptacion, y al momento de hacer select lo estás pasando por md5. osea que estas buscando una clave encriptada en un registro que no lo está.

Comment: vale ese es el error jaj pues entonce no se como meter un usuario y una clave encriptada jaja

Comment: Para insertar datos, `INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES('nombre_usuario',MD5('password'));` para comprobar, `$password = MD5($_POST['password']);`. MD5 es inseguro, te recomiendo buscar información al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a convertir la contraseña en md5 para luego buscarla, debes de guardar la contraseña con el md5 en la base de datos. Ej:

$pass = MD5($password);
"INSERT INTO users (usuario, contrasena) VALUES('valentine', '$pass');"